# Kafka connector for elasticsearch exception

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I got exception when I run my kafka connector for elasticsearch. I installed confluent kafka connector for elasticsearch, and I have configured it as follow :

`{
    "name": "ElasticsearchSinkConnector2",
    "config":{
        "connector.class":
           "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
        "topics": "test",
        "tasks.max": 1,
        "connection.url": "elasticsearch:9200",
        "type.name": "log",
        "key.ignore":true,
        "schema.ignore":true
  }
}`

But got this exception :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/searchbox/action/Action
atio.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:118)
at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:49)
at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:49)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:302)
atorg.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:191)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.searchbox.action.Action
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 11 more`
```

Comment: I feel like you should report that here - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/issues/ . Please include what versions of everything you are running.

Comment: And what do you mean you "installed" it? `cp-kafka-connect` docker container already contains the Elastic Connector